# Length does not work. Still takes 255 as length

Tags: sql, hibernate, string-length

I am adding some tables with Hibernate. But when I set the length for a String, it still takes on a length of 255 positions in the table.

```
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" length="10" name="usm" type="java.lang.String">
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You have set your hbm2ddl to "update" (or "create"), not to "verify" or others?

Comment: It is set to first drop the table, if it already exists, and then to create the table.

Comment: It seems to work when I put the "length" in the "column"-tag.